# Does Cortex-A8 support software interrupts?

Tags: interrupt, cortex-a8

Does Cortex-A8 support Software Generated Interrupt, i.e is there any instruction to generate a software interrupt in Cortex-A8?

The manual mentions about SWI instruction (SVC), but this instruction seems to be used when changing the mode from user to SuperVisor mode.

Can I assume there is no Software Interrupt/Exception instruction supported in Cortex-A8?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. In the Cortex-A8 is the only software generated interrupt the
Supervisor Call (SVC) instruction to enter Supervisor mode. The SVC handler reads the opcode to extract the SVC function number. A SVC handler returns by executing the following instruction, irrespective of the processor operating state:

```
MOVS PC, R14_svc
```

This action restores the PC and CPSR, and returns to the instruction following the SVC. IRQs are disabled when a software interrupt occurs.

see [enter link description here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/CHDHACJE.html)